# In Presto how to query a cloumn which no value

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

I have a integer column which is empty. How to query that I tried

```
select * from table where target_status_code = null
```

but it did not return anything

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should use `is null` to check the integer column which is empty:

```sql
select * from table where target_status_code is null
```